# Graph of $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$

Tags: definite-integrals

> The area (in sq. units) of the region bounded by the curve $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1,x,y\ge0$, and the tangent to it at the point $(\frac14,\frac14)$ is : $\frac1{24}/\frac1{8}/\frac1{36}/\frac1{12}$?

To start this, I need to make graph of $\sqrt x+\sqrt y=1$, I guess. But not able to do so. It's neither circle nor ellipse. How to approach?

Comment: You can parametrize the boundary using the fourth powers of sine and cosine. Otherwise you could also express y in terms of x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/pa5jpk3x2t

Above is the plot of the curve.

so the area from $x \in [0,1]$ is 
$$A(x) = \int_{0}^{1}(1-\sqrt{x})^2 dx$$
You can easily see that the required area R(x) is 
$$R(x) = I(x) - \text{Area of triangle}$$

You can see from the graph that the area of triangle bounded by the tangent and the $x$ axis and the $y$ axis is $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{2}$. The integral $I(x) = \frac{1}{6}$
Hence, $R(x) = \frac{1}{24}$

---

Edited the answer I had some misconceptions about bounding the curve

---

So it is not possible to exactly plot the curve but it is possible to plot the tangent and plot a rough curve to get the above idea. The key thing is that the curve passes through $(0,1),(1/4,1/4),(1,0)$. And the tangent intersects the $y$ and the $x$ -axis at $(0,1/2)$ and $(1/2,0)$. From this info I draw the following.[image]

I think we can do the rest from this image too. You get the limits of the integration, you get the area of the triangle to be subtracted. To do this under one minute will still be hard for me at least.

Comment: Hey, thanks, my main confusion is - how to draw the graph?

Comment: Cant add image in the comment so edited the answer. You don't really need to accurately draw the curve.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{0}^{1}(1-\sqrt{x})^2\,dx - \int_{0}^{1/2}\left(\frac{1}{2}-x\right)\,dx $$
is the wanted area (can you figure out why?), so the answer is given by
$$ 1-\frac{4}{3}+\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{8}=\color{red}{\frac{1}{24}}. $$

Comment: Sorry, not able to figure out the integral.

Comment: @Ramit: $$ \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}=1 \to \sqrt{y} = 1-\sqrt{x} \to y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2 $$ as suggested in the comments. $y=\frac{1}{2}-x$ is the equation of the tangent line.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I had figured that out. But I could not work out the limits.

Answer (score 1):

The graph is an arc of parabola with line bissector (y=x) as its axis of symmetry. Here is why.

Setting $\sqrt{x}=t \iff x=t^2$, we have $y=1-\sqrt{x}=1-t \iff y^2=t^2-2t+1$

Using rotation by $+\pi/4$ combined with homothety with ratio $\sqrt{2}$ :

$$\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\1& \ \ 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}t^2\\t^2-2t+1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}2t-1\\2t^2-2t+1\end{pmatrix}$$

from which, plugging $t=\frac{(X+1)}{2}$ in the expression of $Y$, you get $Y$ as a quadratic in $X$.

Comment: Hi, thanks. This question is from a competitive exam, where we have on an average one minute per question. Thanks for elaborating about parabola. I also wish to know how to solve it quickly. Thanks.

Comment: @aarbee Which exam is this from? i had been given a similar question a few weeks back.

Comment: @Ercanayan JEE (India)

Comment: @aarbee oh tabhi toh, did you give the exam?

Comment: @Ercanayan I couldn't clear the exam when I took it. Are you preparing for it? Or already done with it?

Comment: @aarbee gave it this year, over the years mathematics section has evolved.